# Routes not displaying on Refresh on Deploying Svelte App on Github pages

Tags: routes, single-page-application, github-pages, svelte, svelte-3

I was looking for a fix to "refresh doesn't work on components" issue. I found that it works by adding -s in package.json as mentioned here https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing/issues/32#issuecomment-495923463.

BUT when I deployed my app, I found that it does NOT work in the production build. Any idea why so?

I just want that my Svelte SPA pages do refresh when I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that by creating a 200.html file (which basically has same content as index.html), it all works. Add that file to your production build folder.

As mentioned by @rixo as well, it is not documented (just 404.html, they must have added 200.html recently), but that's how you tell gh pages to send the index to any request for an unknown page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do essentially the same thing for your prod setup. Your server needs to serve the index.html for any URL, instead of 404, with SPAs, to let the client-side router take over.

How you do this entirely depends on your prod dev server. You have middlewares for express and the like, and generally standalone web servers have an option for that, often called `fallback` or `single` or something like this...

How are you serving your application in prod?

Comment: I have not used a server for the SPA. I have developed it entirely client side with a couple of APIs integration in them. That is why I find it difficult because I am not using any Express server or any server in general.

Comment: You have to have a server somehow, if not one that you control, one that is provided by your hosting solution. Even if you app works entirely client-side, the client's files must be transferred to the client. How / where do you want to deploy for prod?

Comment: I am planning to deploy it to github pages. Also, I found that by creating a 200.html file (which is basically has same content as index.html), it all works. Do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: Seems that it is not documented (just 404.html, they must have added 200.html recently), but that's how you tell gh pages to send the index to any request for an unknown page. So that's the answer to your question, congrats! You should mention gh pages in the title of your question, post your solution as an answer, and accept it. Could probably be useful to others.

Comment: Sure, would do that. Thank you so much. I really appreciate you helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I was looking to solve this as well. I fixed it by creating a 404.html in netlify and adding it to production build in public folder. Then I added these scripts:

"start": "sirv public -s",
"start:dev": "sirv public --dev -s"

to package.json.
Works for me.